# Удалить уведомление

Tags: android, уведомления

Возможно ли удалить запланированное уведомление, чтобы оно вообще не появлялось в статус баре?
Метод

```
notificationManager.cancel(id);
```

стирает уведомление именно из статус бара.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если уведомления задаются через AlarmManager, то через него их и надо отменять

```
    final AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ctx.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intentToTimerReceiver = new Intent(ctx.getApplicationContext(), ReceiverTimer.class);
    intentToTimerReceiver.setAction(RECEIVER_TIMER_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx.getApplicationContext(), ID,
            intentToTimerReceiver,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    am.cancel(pendingIntent);
    pendingIntent.cancel();
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло